# ASP.NET v1.1 Could not load type TBRWEB.frmLogin

Tags: asp.net

I have a web app that I wanted copy to a new project.

I created the new app with VS2003 and copied across the web forms, config, global asa, etc. and made sure IIS says it is a web app.

However, I still get this error when I run the app using IE from VS IDE:

```
ASP.NET v1.1 Could not load type TBRWEB.frmLogin
```

I also made sure the assembly name and root namespace are the same as original.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

These error normally occurs if the .aspx page or the Global.asax page contains a reference to a code-behind module and if the application has not been built.

Look in your project settings and check the value of the **default namespace** (in the application section).

Then check the **"inherits" attribute in the control header** of your ascx control (and yll other aspx/ascx files). I suspect that these two names are not the same. Creating a new project maybe you choose a different name which became the default namespace.

The simplest solution would be to change the namespace of your project to TBRWEB, if that is an option.

if it is not that easy, then my follow-up questions are:

- Did you successfully build (compile) the application?
- If it's a ASP.NET web site (not web project), did you forget to copy the .cs/.vb files in the App_Code folder?